# How to track login of users in a Java Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring

The application is already configured via Spring Session to log user sessions into a SQL database. Now I would like to log the user sessions into my own database table for purposes of tracking user login data. What are some possible ways to do so?

Comment: What is "SQL database" and how is  "my own database table " different?

Comment: by SQL database i just meant to say a relational database.
from my understanding when you use Spring session, it creates a SPRING_SESSION table in the database you specify in the configuration. I wanted to log data to a table that I create.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a bean which implements `ApplicationListener<>`, for either `AuthenticationSuccessEvent` or `InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent` events.

See for further info:

- http://www.baeldung.com/spring-events
- https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-application-events-and-listeners

Comment: Thank you Destan.

Answer (score 0):

The original poster has likely moved on from this question, but others my find this tutorial useful as I did:

[Keep Track of Logged In Users with Spring Security](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-track-logged-in-users)

Basically, it makes use of the HttpBindingSessionListener to keep track of a list of currently logged in users.