# Session Attributes using spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

Could anyone help me?

How can add session attributes if i am using spring security?

Let me explain:

When an user is logged, I want to create an object called Filters and other called Site

The aim of Filters object is to keep the different filters that the user can apply in a table.

The aim of Site object is to keep the site or place where the user works, to determine the info that can see in accordance of the Site.

I tried to create private objects variables in the main controller, but when multiple user are logged, they share the variables

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50175930/how-to-track-login-of-users-in-a-java-spring-boot-application).

If you what to use `HttpSession` to store this information, you should get the user identity first in your `Controller` and use it as key when you store in the session(Concat information when key exist in the session). 
For example 
You can use this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31159075/how-to-find-out-the-currently-logged-in-user-in-spring-boot).

Answer (score 0):

*I tried to create private objects variables in the main controller, but when multiple user are logged, they share the variables*

For the above issue, I would recommend you to put session attribute detail with the key as user_id which is unique for each user so once the user is logged in you can get the details (session attribute value) with user id.